# Call Soap API through SUDS in python with SSL and headers

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, soap, suds

I have a soap api and i want to call it with suds in python.  I have install the suds and able to connect with the soap api.

`client = Client("http://my_sevone_appliance/soap3/api.wsdl")`

But catch is i have to send some headers and extra headers to the soap api and i also have to send the ssl file in TLSv1.

`ssl.wrap_socket()`
Remember python version is 2.7

but somehow  i am not able to do that.
can someone help me how to call the soap api from suds and pass headers in that and also ssl. thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.I have done all these thing in **python** and **suds**. Please install **suds.**

So first i have write a tranport.py script in python which actually take the cert and key file and pass it to suds client. here is the code.

```
import urllib2, httplib, socket
from suds.transport.http import HttpTransport, Reply, TransportError
class HTTPSClientAuthHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):

    def __init__(self, key, cert):
        urllib2.HTTPSHandler.__init__(self)
        self.key = key
        self.cert = cert

    def https_open(self, req):
        #Rather than pass in a reference to a connection class, we pass in
        # a reference to a function which, for all intents and purposes,
        # will behave as a constructor
        return self.do_open(self.getConnection, req)

    def getConnection(self, host, timeout=300):
        return httplib.HTTPSConnection(host,
                                      key_file=self.key,
                                      cert_file=self.cert)
class HTTPSClientCertTransport(HttpTransport):

    def __init__(self, key, cert, *args, **kwargs):
        HttpTransport.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.key = key
        self.cert = cert

    def u2open(self, u2request):
        """
        Open a connection.
        @param u2request: A urllib2 request.
        @type u2request: urllib2.Requet.
        @return: The opened file-like urllib2 object.
        @rtype: fp
        """
        tm = self.options.timeout
        url = urllib2.build_opener(HTTPSClientAuthHandler(self.key, self.cert))
        if self.u2ver() < 2.6:
            socket.setdefaulttimeout(tm)
            return url.open(u2request)
        else:
            return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
```

to use the above one and call soap api successfully i use following code.

```
url = <wsdl url of soap api eg: url ="http://my_sevone_appliance/soap3/api.wsdl">
pem = <is the key file>  
cert = <is the cert>   
c = Client(url, transport=HTTPSClientCertTransport(pem, cert))
```

then i call the function which i want to hit. you can see all fucntion you want to hit by.

```
print c
```

Here i have to use the headers also to send in the soap. So i have to pass the headers also(Optional).

```
import ast
headers = '{}'
c.set_options(headers=ast.literal_eval(headers))
```

i have to use ast because you have to send headers in json format. Then i call the function.

```
xml=<the xml data  which you want to send>
example : 
 xml ='<soap:Env xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://www.abc1.com/services">
             <soap:Header/>
             <soap:Body>
                <ser:getName>
                   <ser:ver>1</ser:ver>
                   <ser:syncId>222</ser:syncID>
                   <ser:mobileNo>0987654321</ser:mobileNo>
                </ser:getBalance>
             </soap:Body>
          </soap:Env>'
```

now hit the soap function

```
 c.service.getName(__inject={'msg': xml})
```

here getName is my function in soap api.

thats it. Ask me if you have any question.

Answer (score 2):

```
#**If you don't have any cert file and key:**

import ast
from suds.client import Client
headers='{}'
url = <wsdl url of soap api eg: url ="http://my_sevone_appliance/soap3/api.wsdl">
client = Client(url,location=url)
client.options.cache.clear()
c.set_options(headers=ast.literal_eval(headers))
c=client.service.<service name>(__inject={'msg': xml})    #eg. c.service.getName(__inject={'msg': xml})


#**fetching data from response**
#for example if the output will:
# c.CustomerInfo
#(ArrayOfCustomer){
#   Customer[] = 
#      (Customer){
#         Account = xyz
#         AccountType = abc
#         Account_TypeID = mno
#         Address = None
#         Address2 = None
#         City = Pune
#},
#}

#then fetch like:  c.CustomerInfo.Customer[0].Account
```

Comment: Could you give more details on what your code does ?

Comment: It calls SOAP service with given headers and xml parameters in python and fetch the parameters from the response